# Load row from MySQL depending on php?id=*

Tags: php, mysql, row

I'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL (experienced with other languages). Basically I want to load data from a row relative to its id stated in the URL. Example, load the 3rd row when "index.php?id=3"

Heres what I've managed to do so far: http://pastie.org/1436865

I pretty sure this question has been asked a million times over, but I don't know what term to search far and have not been able to find anything so far :S

Thanks guys

Comment: +1 for a clear question with a link to code. I don't have time to answer all of it right now, but I'll tell you that you can get the id from your querystring using `$id = (int) $_GET['id'];`. Good luck!

Comment: Gentleman and a scholar you are sir :) That did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=".$id);
while($res = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    echo $res->columnname;
}
```

Of course, you should check input parameters, etc. This is only approach.

Comment: you can read also documentation to mysql functions on php.net. For example, mysql_fetch_object page you can found here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Comment: OR aditionaly you can use `SELECT * FROM likes OFFSET " . $_GET['id']` LIMIT 1 ? since he whants the third row , we don't know if he stores id's in his table .

Comment: it seems while is unnecessary here

Comment: @poelinca no, it's both wrong syntax and absolutely unnecessary

Comment: And yes, as wrote Oswald above, you should add new column (named "id", for example) in your table for ordering records. You should add to this column "auto_increment" attribute and make it an primary key for better performance. After that, when you insert a new row in your table, this row will get own id value.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: "SELECT * FROM likes LIMIT 1 OFFSET ".$_GET['id']-1.";" so you where right about the sintax , however why absolutley unnecesary ? do you know how his table looks like ? what if he doesn't stores "id" in his table , this answer will throw and error wouldn't it ?

Comment: @poelinca he should have such a field. Please, rein your imagination, which giving strange results when combined with your ignorance.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: please let's not transform this into an argue nor offend anybody oki ? , just sayin id=3 whont necesarly give you the third row in a table , however limit 1 offset 2 , will allways give you the third row in a table ( if there are atleast 3 rows ) .

Comment: @poelinca Please note Oswald's note. There is no sense in selecting "3rd row"

Comment: Example, load the 3rd row when "index.php?id=3"

Comment: @poelinca "I'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL" he said. So, it's better not to follow his question literally, but show him right way

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: you're right , that's why i gaved +1 on you're answer .

Comment: @poelinca thanks, so here is your mistake: Mysql LIMIT doesn't use offset. it's just LIMIT 2,1

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: can be used with "LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2" , and for a starter i tought it would be easyer to understand .

Comment: @poelinca oops, by bad. I apologize then

Answer (score 1):

The part `id=3...` is called *query string* and you can access it using the `$_GET` array (see [PHP: Predefined Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)).

BTW: It does not make sense to load the 3rd row from a database table, because the rows in the database table do not have an ordering (so instead of a list of rows, a set of records is a more appropriate analogy in this case). Records are usually identified by a so called primary key and you have to make sure yourself, that your database tables have a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you prefer array's instead of objects try something like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=".(int)$_GET['id']." LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['column'];
}
```

or if you like indexed columns

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

or both (column names and indexes):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo $row[0].'-'.$row['column'];
}
```

You can even use this if you need only one row:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=".(int)$_GET['id']);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on all these not-so-clear but working examples, you can make a **function**:

```
function getRow($query){
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error(mysql_error." in ".$query);
    return array();
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
  if ($row) return $row;
  return array();
}
```

then store it into some library file, then include this file into your script and call with just single line

```
$data = getRow("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=".intval($_GET['id']));
```

Also note Oswald's note, it's very important. You can't and you shouldn't rely on the row's relative position as there is no position at all. A DB table is a heap, not ordered list. 
Use certain unique field value to address certain row. That's the way to go